# How can I write the return of a function in javascript over an image in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html

So, I want to write the output of a function over an image. But what I'm getting is the text goes under the image:

[image]

I wanted that number over the image, under the word "Saldo".

```js
var saldo = 10;
var tempo=setInterval(function(){debita()}, 1000);

function debita(){
 
 if (saldo > 0){
  saldo = saldo - 0.0014;
  document.getElementById("Saldo").innerHTML = saldo;
 }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
 <script src="functions.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

 <div style="position: relative;">
  <img  src="Screen 1.jpg" usemap="#Map" />
  <map name="Map" id="Map">
   <area href="continuar.html" shape="poly" coords="54,57,15,92,89,92" />
  </map>
  <div style="position: absolute;"><p id="Saldo"></p></div>
 </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That's what elements do, if you want to move an element, it's just basic CSS ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're in the right direction with the `position: relative;` on the parent and `position: absolute;` on the child, but you might need to add `top` and `left` positions to the child, for example:

```
<div style="position: absolute; top: 10px; left: 5px;"><p id="Saldo"></p></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
img {
    border: 2px solid black;   
}

#container {
    position: relative;    
}

#example {
   position: absolute;
   top: 25px;
   width: 50px;
   left: 25px; 
   color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ulso.png">
    <div id="example">Number goes here</div>
</div>
```